# Use of each in the question

Tags: word-usage

Suppose that I bought four apple from greengrocer and I want two apples in package. In this case if say the sentence below would it be correct?

> 1)Can you put them in two packages of two apples each?

In this sentence does  “each” describe apple or package?

Comment: The sentence is natural, except "bag" would be better than "package", unless they're being wrapped up in paper or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can say "Suppose I buy...and I want" or "Suppose I bought...and I wanted."

In the UK greengrocers have bags, not packages.

We would ask, "Can you put them in two bags, with two in each?" or "Could you....." People say either.

Answer (score 0):

You could say something like:

> Can you put them in two bags, with two apples in each bag.

You could omit the final "bag" and the sentence is still clear.

You wouldn't use an expression like "two packages of two apples each". "Package" is not the right word to use and you should use an expression like "in each" for clarity.

Comment: Drat! Didn't see you there. Has my answer added in any way to the sum of human knowledge? Only the bit about tenses. I might delete it.

Comment: Is “two bags of two apples each” meaningless?

Comment: It would mean the same, but just isn't how I'd express that idea.  It is an odd thing to say. I haven't been to a shop where the greengrocer puts things in bags for about 20 years.  And when I did I never asked for my apples to be split in two bags.  So if you need this odd thing you'd need to explain it ... So you'd use a nice clear sentence like I gave instead of the less clear one you used.  But actually I don't think you are *ever* going to use this sentence.  I never have.

Comment: @Foreign student: People would know what you meant, but James K and I have given you better ways to ask. Btw, according to your question, apples have already been mentioned: "Suppose that I bought four apple from a greengrocer and I wanted..." So really you don't need to say "apples" again. That's why I suggested,  "Can you put them in two bags, with two in each?" You could say,"Please divide these fruits equally between two bags", but it's less colloquial.

Comment: @James K: Not for 20 years? The greengrocer whose stall's at the end of Electric Avenue in my manor **always** puts things in brown paper bags.

Comment: Nearly all shops are self-service.  If you ask the shelf stackers at Tesco to put things in two bags...